# Using "this" in a callback vs external variable and the garbage collector

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I just stumbled on the [IndexedDB example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#JavaScript_Content) which contains the following:

```
function openDb() {
    var req = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        // Better use "this" than "req" to get the result
        // to avoid problems with garbage collection.
        // db = req.result;
        db = this.result;
    };
    // Rest of code omitted for brevity
}
```

What is the problem with the garbage collector that should better be avoided?

Comment: You can avoid the closure variable.

Comment: Using `req` requires the req variable to be stored in memory, where using `this` allows the `req` variable to be garbage collected. Seems like micro-optimization though in most cases, this is probably just an example for explanation.

Comment: @thefourtheye yes in the above example that would be right, but if you follow the link you'll see that there's req.onerror as well. So the variable is needed

Comment: @JamesG. thanks, it certainly sounds like some extreme micro-optimization.

Comment: Not even a "micro" optimisation: both `this` and `req` would go out of scope simultaneously.

Comment: @James G.: that's fundamentally incorrect: it's not variables that are garbage collected, but the data they refer to. So the "where using this allows the req variable to be garbage collected" phrase makes little to no sense.

Comment: Well, oldIE had GC problems with circular references involving closure callback references to the DOM object they were attached to, but none of the browsers supporting IndexedDB should have these

Comment: The comment and code [are from 2012](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB$compare?locale=en-US&to=334421&from=325685)

Comment: @Bergi I remember it was IE6 that had such issues, which has already been dead in 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This advice looks weird: the object the `req` variable refers to (the same the `this` would refer to) as well as the anonymous function objects (which are hold by `onsuccess`, `onerror` and `onupgradeneeded` properties) would all be garbage collectible simultaneously as soon as the query has completed and callbacks have been invoked.

Technically - `req` represents another reference to the object; practically it cannot cause any "problems with garbage collection".

To summarize: it's neither an "optimisation" nor "micro optimisation", both would perform equally.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell if you reference 'req', 'openDb' invocation scope is tied to 'onsuccess' (as parent scope) so you create a closure. If - on the other hand - you reference only 'this', the 'openDb' invocation scope can be discarded as soon as you exit the function.

What might be causing confusion is that the object refered to by 'req' lives beyond the lifetime of 'openDb' - it is not used exclusiveley from within that function.